# How to fix redirecting issues with Ajax when using processing a form

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to use AJAX to submit my form. It validates well but fails to redirect after successfully processing. I need it to redirect when `response == "ok"`

```js
$('document').ready(function() {
  function submitForm() {
    var data = $("#login-form").serialize();
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'loginprocess.php',
      data: data,
      beforeSend: function() {
        $("#loginerror").fadeOut();
        $("#login_button").html('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-transfer"></span> &nbsp; sending ...');
      },
      success: function(response) {
        if (response == "ok") {
          $("#login_button").html('<img src="ajax-loader.gif" /> &nbsp; Signing In ...');
          window.location = 'welcome.php';
        } else {
          $("#loginerror").fadeIn(1000, function() {
            $("#loginerror").html('<div class="alert alert-danger"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span> &nbsp; ' + response + ' !</div>');
            $("#login_button").html('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> &nbsp; Sign In');
          });
        }
      }
    });
    return false;
  }
});
```

Comment: Your `window.location` assignment should be working. Check for errors in the console, and make sure that the AJAX request is completing successfully.

Comment: Ajax has an error function also (just like success). Always use it to catch errors. How do you know the Ajax is not returning any error? What does "it validates" mean?

Comment: @NawedKhan There was a form validation code that was not added, so the form validation worked. whenever the query from loginprocess.php is successful, it echoes OK and not redirect to the welcome.php

Comment: Use the Network tab of Developer Tools to see the complete response. Also, in case there's extra whitespace, use `if (response.trim() == "ok")`

Comment: @Enitopapa did you try console.log(response) to see what is the response? is it 'ok' or 'OK' or '{ok}' or a whole lot of html with ok somewhere in the middle.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks the trim function worked also

Comment: @NawedKhan Really this is my first time of using console.log(). There was an extra space as in " ok". Also I changed the response to data. And it worked. I'm so glad for the quick responses of everyone.

Answer (score 0):

It was fixed by changing the response to data, using console.log(data) i realised that there was an extra space before the ok, so i used trim as advised. below is the new code that worked.

Thanks to y'all for saving the day-night.